# Python 3 not reading a JSON file right

Tags: python, json, file, python-3.x, parsing

I have some json files created by powershell using the `ConvertTo-Json` command. The content of the json file looks like

```
{
    "Key1":  "Value1",
    "Key2":  "Value2"
}
```

I ran the python interpreter to see if I could read the file but I get this weird output

```
>>> f=open('test.json', 'r')
>>> f.read()
'ÿ\xfe{\x00\n\x00\n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00"\x00K\x00e\x00y\x001\x00"\x00:\x00 \x00 \x00"\x00V\x00a\x00l\x00u\x00e\x001\x00"\x00,\x00\n\x00\n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00"\x00K\x00e\x00y\x002\x00"\x00:\x00 \x00 \x00"\x00V\x00a\x00l\x00u\x00e\x002\x00"\x00\n\x00\n\x00}\x00\n\x00\n\x00'
```

For some reason all the characters are escaped byte characters and there's the weird `ÿ` at the begninning (powershell error?).

The weird thing is this:

```
>>> f=open('test.json', 'r')
>>> str=f.read()
>>> type(str)
<class 'str'>
>>> json.loads(str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Rutvik_Choudhary\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Rutvik_Choudhary\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Rutvik_Choudhary\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

So the input is a string, but the json module can't parse it (`json.load(f)` return the same error). What is causing this error? Is it a python thing, a powershell thing, a json thing?

Comment: What character encoding is used for your json. Definitely not ascii or utf-8. Possibly a multi byte encoding.

Comment: Can you open the `test.json` file generated by PowerShell in say, notepad? I'm betting the file got damaged or scrambled some how. Because JSON is plain text and that doesn't look like plain text at all.

Comment: Your file appears to be encoded in UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by jwodder, PowerShell has encoded your json using UTF-16LE. To get this data into json correctly, you need to open the file using the correct encoding. eg.

```
with open("test.json", "r", encoding="utf16") as f:
    json_string = f.read()
my_dict = json.loads(json_string)
```

You don't need to tell Python which variant of UTF-16 is being used. This is the purpose of the first two bytes of the text file. It's called a Byte Order Mark (BOM). It lets a program know if UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE has been used to encode the text file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) at the start of your file. You can verify it in a hex editor or with a good text editor (Notepad++ shows if BOM is present).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load text files with Unicode BOM headers, like yours you should better use to codecs.open functions instead of open as the default open is not able to interpret the BOM.

Or you can have a look at [tendo.unicode](http://tendo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tendo/unicode.html) - a small library that I wrote that can improve life for people that are not used to Unicode texts.